# Php form validation with Ajax and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

Everything works fine with php ,error messages function properly but if i try to do it with ajax it doesnt work. I used diffrent jQuery codes and plain javascript but i was only able to prevent the button's default reaction and stop the page from relaoding but i couldnt get the error-messages to show. i am aware that you have to get the error-messages display with javascript and run the php as backend script but i couldnt get it to work. i would appreciate any help.

here is my html form code:

```
  <?php require('contact-script.php'); 

?>


<div class="container">  
            <form id="contact" action="index.php" method="POST">
              <h3 id="test"  >Contact Form</h3>
              <h4>Contact us for custom quote</h4>

              <span class="error"  ><?php echo $errors['first']; ?></span>
              <fieldset>
                <input id="first" placeholder="First Name" name="first" type="text" value="<?php echo $first ?>" tabindex="1"  >
              </fieldset>

              <span class="error" ><?php echo $errors['last']; ?></span>
              <fieldset>
                <input id="last" placeholder="Last Name" name="last" type="text" value="<?php echo $last ?>" tabindex="1"  >
              </fieldset>

              <span class="error" ><?php echo $errors['mail']; ?></span>
              <fieldset>
                <input id="mail" placeholder="Your Email Address" name="mail" type="text" value="<?php echo $mail ?>" tabindex="2" >
              </fieldset>

              <span class="error" ><?php echo $errors['subject']; ?></span>
              <fieldset>
                <input id="subject" placeholder="Subject" name="subject" type="text" value="<?php echo $subject ?>" tabindex="2" >
              </fieldset>

              <fieldset>
                <textarea id="message" placeholder="Type your message here...." name="message" type="text" value="<?php echo $message ?>" tabindex="5" ></textarea>
              </fieldset>
              <span class="error" ><?php echo $errors['message']; ?></span>

              <fieldset>
                <button  id="formBtn" name="submit" type="submit" >Submit</button>
              </fieldset>
            </form>
</div>
```

here is my php code:

```
//defining Variables 
$first = $last = $mail = $message = $subject = "";
$name_error = ""; $mail_error = ""; $message_error = "";

$errors = array( 'mail'=>'' , 'first'=> '' ,  'last'=>'', 'subject'=>'', 'message'=>'');



if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $mail = htmlspecialchars($_POST['mail']);
    $first = htmlspecialchars($_POST['first']);
    $last = htmlspecialchars($_POST['last']);
    $subject = htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject']);
    $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);


    //check mail    
    if (empty($_POST['mail'])) {
        $errors['mail'] = 'Bitte geben Sie eine E-mail Adresse an <br />';


    }
    else {
        $mail = $_POST['mail'];
        if (!filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errors['mail'] = 'Bitte geben Sie eine gültige E-mail an';


        }
    }

    //check first name
    if(empty($_POST['first'])) {
        $errors['first'] = 'Bitte geben Sie einen Namen an <br />';



    }
    else {
        if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/', $first)) {
            $errors['first']= 'Name darf nur Buchstaben und Lehrzeichen enthalten ';


        }
    }

    //check last name
    if(empty($_POST['last'])) {
        $errors['last'] = 'Bitte geben Sie einen Nachnamen an <br />';


    }
    else {
        if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/', $last)) {
            $errors['last']= 'Name darf nur Buchstaben und Lehrzeichen enthalten';


        }
    }


    if(empty($_POST['subject'])) {
        $errors['subject'] = 'Bitte geben Sie ein Anliegen an <br />';


    }
    else {
        if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/', $subject)) {
            $errors['subject']= 'Anliegen darf nur Buchstaben und Lehrzeichen enthalten ';


        }
    }

    //check for message
    if(empty($_POST['message'])) {
        $errors['message']= 'Bitte schreiben Sie eine Nachricht <br />';

    }

    if (array_filter($errors)) {

    }else {
        $mailTo = "info@blanc-code.de";
        $headers = "From: ".$mail;
        $text = "Sie haben eine e-mail von ".$first." ".$last." erhalten.\n\n".$message;

        mail($mailTo, $subject, $text, $headers);

    }
```

i tryed this code for example:

```
function submitForm() {
    getBtn = document.querySelector('#formBtn');
    getBtn.disabled = true;

    let formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("mail", document.querySelector('mail').value);
    formdata.append("first", document.querySelector('first').value);
    formdata.append("last", document.querySelector('last').value);
    formdata.append("subject", document.querySelector('subject').value);

    let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", "contact-script.php");

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            if(http.responseText == "success") {
            }else {
                getBtn.disabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
    http.send(formdata);
```

or this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var first = $("#first").val();
        var last = $("#last").val();
        var mail = $("#mail").val();
        var subject = $("#subject").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();
        $(".error").load("contact-script.php", {
            first: first,
            last: last,
            mail: mail,
            subject: subject,
            message: message
        });
    });
});
```

there was more but this should give you a clue

Comment: We kinda need the JS code to determine whats wrong with it

Comment: @Lapskaus i edited some examples that i tried